# Why IDEA shows java files as invalid in my Android project?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am trying to build apk from [this](https://github.com/omertex/AndroidNavigationDrawerTabs) repository.

I have problem: idea show .java files as invalid, you can see it on this pic:
[image]

What am I doing?

1. I download [mentioned (git)](https://github.com/omertex/AndroidNavigationDrawerTabs) sources and copy sources to some directory
2. I open this directory from IDEA as directory
3. In project settings I am setting Project SDK as Android 22 and create `Android` module in Modules section
4. Downloaded sources require `android-support-v7-appcompat` lib, so I am getting many errors, like IDEA can't find theme in xml
   [image]
5. To remove this error, I had added library `android-support-v7` in project settings, added module `\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\` to modules and set `android-support-v7` module as dependency for my main android module
6. I invalidate cache and restart IDEA

After this steps I got xml's without errors about theme (because appcompat library was added), but java files are not looking valid, as I showed on picture above.

Also, I got red `Main activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml file` and I can't go to the declaration of the activity by clicking `ctrl + LMB` on it.

[image: d]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the source dir.

Right click on `com`'s parent folder, then `Mark directory as` and `sources root`.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on java folder ->mark directory as -> sources root
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to check you package...com.yourproject in the imports, try to import the R packge and the rest of your packge like class and other things like import com.yourproject.R.... In the Android Studio rigth click, F4 you also can ser the project proprieties....all i see is that post a awser and let me help you witj this